# SSAS tabular project does not show query mode options

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, sql-server-data-tools, tabular, azure-analysis-services

I am working on a SSAS tabular model project in VS 2019 and deploying to a Azure Analysis Server. But I am not able to see the query mode option under deployment properties, can anybody help ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SylMP.png)
TIA.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**To enable DirectQuery:**

In **Visual Studio**, in the **Properties** pane for the **Model.bim** file, change the property, **DirectQuery Mode**, to **On**.

[image]

**Reference:** [Enable DirectQuery mode in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/enable-directquery-mode-in-ssdt?view=asallproducts-allversions)

Comment: I have the Direct query mode for model.bim file enabled/turned on. But I am looking to change the query mode to use Direct Query with In memory option(mixed mode), and I cannot see that anywhere .

Comment: Tabular models in both in-memory and DirectQuery modes are supported. In-memory mode (default) tabular models support multiple data sources.

This is the default configuration on your tabular database unless you force to change it to direct query mode. Same as most of the In-memory databases out there, a tabular database in In-memory or Import mode all the data reside in-memory. Checkout: http://nisalbi.blogspot.com/2017/10/ssas-tablular-directquery-mode-vs-in.html

Comment: If it is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.